# How to keep repeating switch statement C#

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I'm writing a program to create a list of books, and I have written a few methods for that purpose. I want to display a list of options for which method to call, then once they choose an option, keep displaying the options until they choose to exit.

This is all I have so far:

```
List<Book> books = new List<Book>();

switch
{
    case 1:
        CardCatalog.AddBook(books);
        break;
    case 2:
        CardCatalog.ListBooks(books);
        break;
    default:
        CardCatalog.Save(books);
        break;
}
```

I've already written the methods, now I just need this to work. If they choose option 1 or 2, the switch statement should be repeated. If they choose option 3, CardCatalog.Save() should be executed and the switch statement should NOT repeat.

I would like this statement to be repeated each time as well:

```
Console.WriteLine("1. Add a Book\n2. List all books\n3. Save and exit");
```

But I don't know how to include it in the switch statement, or even if a switch statement is the right way to go about this (I think it is, though).

Comment: A `case` block doesn't have to end with `break;`.  `continue;` and `return;` are completely valid (and that still isn't the whole list).  Give some thought to how a loop with a `switch` inside will act for each of the actions: `break`, `continue`, `return`.

Comment: Also, your `switch` is missing something... something very important that will change your thinking.

Comment: I know I'm missing the statement in parentheses, but I'm not really testing if something is true or false, so I wasn't sure what to put there.

Comment: Well, what goes into the parentheses is an expression, not a statement.  And it needs to come from somewhere (user input according to your description).  So now you aren't wanting to "repeat the switch", but several things: (1) present the options to the user (2) read their input into a variable (3) process the input with a switch.

Comment: I've figured it out. Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: Hints: Use a loop `do...while` is my personal favorite for stuff like that. Also, use `Int.TryParse` to get an int value from the user input.

Comment: The line `CardCatalog.AddBook(books);` seems to suggest that you have a static class (Pascal casing of `CardCatalog` is typically a class name) with a method `AddBook` (singular) that adds a list of `books` (plural). You code doesn't seem to be well thought through. It would be ideal if you code post your entire code so that we could offer better suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Define a `string` variable called `option`. It will store the option that user inputs. And inside a while loop, prompt user to select an option and store it in `option`. Do your computation (before and inside a `switch` statement). Keep doing this until the input is not one of the predetermined keys.(1 and 2 in this case).

Sample code could look like this:

```
string option = "1"; // Make sure we enter the while loop
while (option == "1" || option == "2")
{
    Console.WriteLine("1. Add a Book\n2. List all books\n3. Save and exit");
    option = Console.ReadLine();

    List<Book> books = new List<Book>(); // Do optional computation here

    switch (option)
    {
        case "1":
            CardCatalog.AddBook(books);
            break;
        case "2":
            CardCatalog.ListBooks(books);
            break;
        default:
            CardCatalog.Save(books);
            break;
    }
}
```

If you get the essence, here is how I would have done it:

```
while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("1. Add a Book\n2. List all books\n3. Save and exit");
    string option = Console.ReadLine();
    if (!Int32.TryParse(option, out int optionAsInt))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter an integer");
        continue;
    }

    List<Book> books = new List<Book>(); // Do optional computation here

    if (optionAsInt == 1)
        CardCatalog.AddBook(books);
    else if (optionAsInt == 2)
        CardCatalog.ListBooks(books);
    else
    {
        CardCatalog.Save(books);
        break;
    }
}
```